# Flutter objectbox : Can I use for production APP (Mobile only Android & iOS)

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-hive, flutter-objectbox

I am new to Flutter and I had started using Hive DB but experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/263). I am looking for one alternative and got ObjectBoxDB.

Is ObjectBox is ready for production use?

I need some recommendations from you all to choose the right Local DB.

My use case is very simple right now to store Key: Value pair data only (Not much data).

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of ObjectBox)

1. ObjectBox-dart is based on the native core that's been used in production for years (Android Java/Kotlin, iOS Swift).
2. ObjectBox-dart package itself has been around for quite some time (since the end of 2019) and is now post 1.0 (which is a big deal for us at ObjectBox). Unfortunately, the current pub.dev tooling doesn't provide any info about the number of apps using it.
3. Has active support from people that work on ObjectBox development full time.

Having said that, it's always up to what you want and I encourage you to try out other packages available on pub.dev that fit your use case.

Comment: How does ObjectBox handle concurrent(by different threads/isolates) write requests? example of my use case: FCM "onBackgroundmessage" call runs in a different isolate, the same time multiple right requests might happen. "Hive" is failing in this case completely. Is there any inbuild solution in ObjectBox?

Comment: I've answered in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519352/objectbox-dart-flutter-multi-isolate-access/68519353