# ObjectBox Dart/Flutter multi-isolate access

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

Creating a separate thread for [a question stated in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112319/flutter-objectbox-can-i-use-for-production-app-mobile-only-android-ios/68195143?noredirect=1#comment121066703_68195143)...

> How does ObjectBox handle concurrent(by different threads/isolates) write requests? example of my use case: FCM "onBackgroundmessage" call runs in a different isolate, the same time multiple write requests might happen. "Hive" is failing in this case completely. Is there any inbuild solution in ObjectBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjectBox for dart is based on a native ObjectBox core library that handles concurrency using [Transactions](https://docs.objectbox.io/transactions). Let me pick out few points relevant to the question:

- Transactions manage multi-threading; e.g. a transaction is tied to a thread and vice versa.
- Read(-only) transactions never get blocked or block a write transaction.
- There can only be a single write transaction at any time; they run strictly one after the other (sequential).

As for the isolates in **Dart/Flutter** - yes, they can safely access the same store, you just need to make sure it really **is** the same native store instance. To do so, you do the following steps:

1. Create a `Store()` instance in your main isolate, as you normally would.
2. Get `ByteData store.reference` which contains the information about the native store.
3. Send this reference to another isolate, via a `SendPort`.
4. In another isolate, receive the reference and open a local `Store` instance, using `Store.fromReference(getObjectBoxModel(), msg as ByteData)`.
5. Now both isolates have their own Dart `Store` instances which internally use the same underlying native store. Therefore, their transactions are synchronized, they both see the same data and get notifications on data changes.

You can see the code I've just described this test case: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/461a948439dcc42f3956b7d21b232eb9c2bc26e1/objectbox/test/isolates_test.dart#L50

Make sure you don't close the store while another isolate is still using it. Better not close it at all - that's best practice in normal applications without huge amounts of background work.

Answer (score 2):

A few years later from the accepted answer, objectbox now has an additional function that can work well with an isolate.

This is the [Store.attach()](https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/Store/Store.attach.html) function. Using this function, you can attach a store by providing the database path without having to worry about a separate isolate closing the store:

> The actual underlying store is only closed when the last store instance is closed (e.g. when the app exits).

In my own case, I had to use the [`workmanager`](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package to execute a background task that depends on the objectbox store.

You can create an "initializer" class like so:

```
class ObjectBox {
  static late final Store store;

  static Future initialize() async {
    var docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var dbPath = p.join(docsDir.path, "objectbox");

    if (Store.isOpen(dbPath)) {
      store = Store.attach(getObjectBoxModel(), dbPath);
    } else {
      store = await openStore(directory: dbPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have this, you can then use the `initialize()` in your isolate. Example with the [`workmanager`](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package:

`main.dart`

```
@pragma("vm:entry-point")
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    await ObjectBox.initialize(); // Initialize in background isolate.

    return true;
  });
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await ObjectBox.initialize(); // Initialize in main isolate

  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

This way, even if you close the database in your main isolate, the background isolate will still continue to function. The underlying store itself is closed once all store instances are closed.